# How to post local storage data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Thanks for your time in reading this post.

I am developing an ecommerce website and used open library simplecart.js to store the cart variables.

I noticed that js file is storing cart items in local storage.

Below is the format that it is getting stored in the local storage

```
simplecartitems(key) {"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":300}}(value)
```

I understood as this data is stored in the client side, there is no way php can access.

Can you please help me how to post this data to php, so that i can access the same from another php file

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you fetch the local storage variables via javascript and ajax them to your php script?

Comment: @Darren : Thanks for your reply.  I dont have any knowledge in javascript.  So i thought of doing it in php.  If possible can you please share me the sample syntax to achieve the above objective.

Comment: You'll need to send the data to your server for your PHP app to process. If you have written an endpoint in PHP that can process request data, you can simply use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to send it to the server.

Comment: @lxe ; Thanks for your reply.  I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try keep it simple, but to fetch elements from local storage, you'll need to harness the [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) method.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('SCI-1'); // whatever your actual key is, in your local storage.
```

I'll leave you to figure out if you want to validate the above, but if it does't find anything, it'll just return `null`.

Now for sending it to the server, You'd be best to check out & use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), harnessing [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.post( "/path/to/your/url", { data: data}, function(response) {
    console.log(response); // handle the response from the server
} );
```

If done correctly, you'll receive your local storage data via `$_POST` in your PHP script. Accessing it is as simple as:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];
```

<sup>*Note: I'll leave you to figure out how you want to test/sanitize/check/validate your data within the PHP script.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot Darren.  You simplified the way.  Now i got some basic idea.  Thanks again.

Comment: One small Doubt, when multiple items are added the local storage looks like the below

Comment: @user3762051 Pleasure mate!

Comment: {"SCI-1":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-1","price":300},"SCI-2":{"quantity":6,"id":"SCI-2","price":280}}, we have two ids here what will be the actual key then

Comment: If you open up your developer tools and find the localstorage, what is the `key` that stores that data?

Comment: Figured out the key is simpleCart_items; That's the value which i need to specify correct?

Comment: @user3762051 Correct, and the data is `JSON`, so on the PHP side, you'll need to decode it, using `json_decode()` :)